# Is the wings of flurry spell broken, when compared to other strong 4th level spells?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, balance

Relevant parts of the spell.

> - **Evocation** [Force]
> - **Level:** Sorcerer 4,
> - **Range:** 30 ft.
> - **Area:** 30-ft.-radius burst
> - **Saving Throw:** Reflex half
> - **Spell Resistance:** Yes
>
> wings that strike at every target in range, dealing 1d6 points of damage per caster level to all designated targets within 30 feet that fail a Reflex saving throw and half that damage to creatures that succeed on the save.
>   Creatures that fail the Reflex save are also dazed for 1 round.
>
> **Special:** A dragonblooded character, or a character with the dragon type, casts this spell at +1 caster level.

It seems just to be on the better end of 4th level spells, like Black Tentacles.

Am I missing it's hidden power?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Daze is incredibly strong. Very, very, very few things are immune to it, and aside from making your Reflex save (or *maybe*<sup>1</sup> having improved evasion), there is no protection to be had against it. And force damage, of course, is extremely reliable. SR: Yes is a downside, but SR still isn’t *terribly* common at 7th level.

By comparison, *black tentacles* does vastly less damage, doesn’t have the advantage of force damage, and grappling both offers much better options for avoiding it and is in any case a far lesser detriment than daze is. SR: No is nice, certainly, but against things without SR (or whose SR you can reliably beat), *wings of flurry* is vastly superior.

That said, perhaps *black tentacles* isn’t the best 4th-level spell to compare *wings of flurry* against. For my money, *solid fog* is the quintessential “ok now that’s just not fair” 4th-level spell, because most classes offer absolutely nothing for getting out of it at 7th level. *Solid fog* is SR: No, has a similar area that can be positioned at considerable range (to *wings of flurry*’s zero), and lasts vastly longer than *wings of flurry*. It also imposes some conditions that are near-impossible to be immune to—the weather domain’s granted ability specifies that you can see through non-magical weather, but that obviously doesn’t cover *solid fog*, and *freedom of movement* probably covers *solid fog*’s movement problems, but that’s about it.

So *solid fog* might be better than *wings of flurry*, though against a spellcaster who can cast *dimension door* and/or *freedom of movement* you might prefer *wings*. And, for that matter, neither *solid fog* nor *wings of flurry* is the most unreasonable spell I’ve mentioned here—that would almost-certainly be *freedom of movement*. And that’s not even getting into stuff like *divination* and *scrying*, which provide no combat option at all but are incredibly campaign-warping when used well.

Of course, the context in which *wings of flurry* came up recently on this site was where we were considering extremely high caster levels. In **that** context, *wings of flurry* can definitely become broken—hundreds of d6s worth of force damage in an area is very unreasonable at any level.

1. <sub>Improved evasion says that when you are subjected to spells like *wings of flurry*, that offer Reflex saves for half damage, you take half damage if you fail the save. So someone with improved evasion takes half the listed damage from *wings of flurry* on a failed save—but is still dazed for one round, since they failed the save and improved evasion says nothing about non-damage effects of spells. A DM *may* allow improved evasion to treat the spell in all ways as if you’d passed the save, but that would be a houserule. Also, since improved evasion is relatively rare, mostly found at high levels in classes that have a lot of incentive to multiclass, and moreover people who have it usually have very-good Reflex saves to begin with, even with this houserule it doesn’t change the conversation very much.</sub>